# Media Capture and Sound Play not working simultaneously

Tags: uwp

In a UWP app, I am analysing a video frame and playing some sound based upon it.
The process of analysing  video frame is continuous but the sound is not getting played while it is running But gets played while debugging.

PlaySound method is awaitable and is on UI thread.

Comment: Could you please send a code sample?

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue in my side, could share a code sample?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mediaplayer you have to set the following [capbility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/background-audio#background-media-playback-manifest-capability):

```
<Capabilities>
    <uap3:Capability Name="backgroundMediaPlayback"/>
</Capabilities>
```

While you are debugging your app your app will not go to background. In that way it will always display.